# How Do I do A Cummulative Subtraction in SQL Views?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have an SQL view that has two fields. I want to calculate reducing balance in weekly terms.

```
TableID  item_no    Qty_shp     Qty_Stk  Balance    posting_date    
1        WTR234       28         500       472       2015/03/09
2        WTR234       42         472       430       2015/03/15
3        WTR234       100        500       400       2015/03/16
4        WTR234       50         400       350       2015/03/22
```

As shown in the table above, I need to be able to calculate the balance on these items on a weekly terms as the `Qty_Stk` reverts to a new value at the beginning of a new week being Monday.

---

From comment of OP

```
TableID item_no Qty_shp Qty_O   Qty_Stk Balance posting_date    
1       WTR234  28      500     500     472     2015/03/09  
2       WTR234  42      500     472     430     2015/03/15  
3       WTR234  100     500     500     400     2015/03/16  
4       WTR234  50      500     400     350     2015/03/22
```

Comment: What would be the expected result?

Comment: What does the source data from the view look like?

Comment: @wewesthemenace: The result should look like what is displayed on the Table in the Balance field.

Comment: @jpw : It look like the displayed table above but without the Balance field.

Comment: If you notice the Balanced is brought forward in the next line to do the next caculation in the same week period. That is the problem for me. I dont seam to know how to get that done within my SQl view

Comment: @Kriz, I edited your post and added the expected result. Is that correct? Is it your expected result?

Comment: Qty_stk and Balance are not present in my SQL View. Only the Qty_O is. I need help to get those fields shown when i run my Views.

Comment: What version my sql server are you using?

Comment: @wewesthemenace: Sql 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using the aggregate function `sum()` with an `over ()` clause. In the query I only partitioned the data based on week, but maybe you want to include the item_no as part of the partitioning too if there are multiple products.

I think this query should give you the correct results (it did for me using your limited sample data).

Edit: i used the setting `SET DATEFIRST 1` when I tried it.

```
select 
    TableID,
    item_no,
    Qty_shp,
Qty_Stk = qty_o - isnull(
   sum(qty_shp) over (
      partition by datepart(week, posting_date) 
      order by posting_date 
      rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
      )
   ,0),
    Balance = qty_o - sum(qty_shp) over (
       partition by datepart(week, posting_date) 
       order by posting_date
    ),
    posting_date    
from your_table
```

This gave me the following output:

```
TableID     item_no    Qty_shp     Qty_Stk     Balance     posting_date
----------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------
1           WTR234     28          500         472         2015-03-09
2           WTR234     42          472         430         2015-03-15
3           WTR234     100         500         400         2015-03-16
4           WTR234     50          400         350         2015-03-22
```

Comment: You may want to add `SET DATEFIRST 1` since according to the OP the week starts at Monday. +1

Comment: @wewesthemenace Indeed, it does for me too so I didn't think to add it in the script. Good point.

Comment: This is great stuff! I tested it with more data and it correctly produces the expected output. Time to learn `rows between...`

Comment: @jpw Thanks for the amazing answer you provided me. It worked like a charm. But now I am having a bit of a problem as I seem not to be able to add it to my SQL VIEW. Do u have any solution for that?

Comment: Here is what I am trying to do in my View:  SET DATEFIRST 1
SELECT  [Item No_], [Production Forecast Name], [Forecast Quantity], [Unit of Measure Code], [Qty_ per Unit of Measure], [Contract Code], [Forecast Price], [Budget Quantity], [Budget Price], [Shipment No_], Entry No_], ([Budget Quantity] - isnull(  sum([SS_Quantity (Base)]) over (
      partition by [Contract Code],[Item No_], datepart(week, [SS_Posting Date])  order by [SS_Posting Date] 
 rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
   ,0) )as [Budget Left]
FROM dbo.RPF_Report_Sales_Forecast_Details_View

Comment: But when I run the SQL view after adding the code it comes with 'code' Error Message: Time out Expired

Comment: @Kriz I can't see anything obvious that would cause a timeout except if you're running the query over a too large dataset and there are missing supporting indexes. The best thing you can do is to look at the query execution plan to see if there are any obvious bottlenecks.

Comment: @jpw Thanks a great deal. My query function well now within my view. Like you said it had to do with my indexes. Once i sorted that out my results where golden. Appreciates a million.